# Decrypt md5 in c programming

Tags: c, encryption

I have a password and  convert it using a online md5 converter and stored it in a file.Now  I need the original string . Is it any possible way to decrypt md5 hash value to original using c program. is there any functions in c program.

Comment: i need to do decryption in c

Comment: You want to get a possible infinite length string from a fixed length string representation?

Comment: i have hash of a string and need to convert back to the original.

Comment: If it was possible to decrypt hashing functions such as md5 or sha then why would you use it to store a password? Also, hashing is not the same as encrypting. It's one-way. **That's the point.** There's nothing to decrypt because the data is not encrypted. A quick Google search and 5 minutes of research would have answered this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely impossible. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

> The security of the MD5 hash function is severely compromised. A
>   collision attack exists that can find collisions within seconds on a
>   computer with a 2.6 GHz Pentium 4 processor (complexity of 224.1).
>   Further, there is also a chosen-prefix collision attack that can
>   produce a collision for two inputs with specified prefixes within
>   hours, using off-the-shelf computing hardware (complexity 239). The
>   ability to find collisions has been greatly aided by the use of
>   off-the-shelf GPUs. On an NVIDIA GeForce 8400GS graphics processor,
>   16–18 million hashes per second can be computed. An NVIDIA GeForce
>   8800 Ultra can calculate more than 200 million hashes per second.
>
> These hash and collision attacks have been demonstrated in the public
>   in various situations, including colliding document files and digital
>   certificates.